# Excel formula referencing it's own column

Tags: excel

I have the following data set:

```
     Name     Class  Amount Position
  1   I1        A      10       P 
  2   I1        O               R 
  3   I1        A      -5       R  
  4   I2        O               P
  5   I2        A       7       P
  6   I2        A      -11      R
```

Typically **Amount** has missing data. I want to populate the missing data from records that match my record on **Name** and **Position** . So in Row-2 I want -5 and in Row-4 I want 7.  If I combine **Name** and **Position** to create a Key-column then I can do an index match or vlookup or just to an index-match with multiple criterion.

What I want to know is what is the most sensible way to go about it?

1. Do I create a new column, say **Amount-2** and write a function in it that pulls up data from **Amount** and does a index-match if it is missing? I don't want to do this because I don't want to add more columns to my dataset.
2. Should I sort the dataset on  **Amount** so I can bunch up all the blank cells together on top and write a formula in them referencing the populated cells below in the same column? Is this method going to be robust to later sorting the data set on other fields or will my formula references go haywire?
3. Write a macro that populates the missing cells? Overkill?

The reason I ask is that I don't want to make my sheet bigger by adding more columns like **Key** or **Amount-2** and I wanted to know what is a robust and clean way to fill in the gaps.

Comment: If you don't want to add any more columns, write a macro to populate the empty cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pros - Nice and simple, guaranteed to work with no surprises.

Cons - Adds to dataset.

2. Pros - avoids adding to dataset

Cons - sounds a bit convoluted to me, sorting may be an issue, though adding a copy/paste values would mitigate.

3. Pros - you've got VBA, you can do whatever you want, no extra columns or cutting/pasting required.

Cons - If you're not conversant with VBA, could be a (small) challenge to write. Could require that new users are trained.

My personal thoughts here are to just go ahead and write a macro. Even if you're not VBA savvy, using the macro recorder, then going through your option #1 (deleting the column at the end of the procedure to avoid the extra field) would get you a long way in this particular instance. You definitely want to go in and clean up the code afterwards, but you'd be quite a bit of the way there.

Map that macro to a shortcut, and updating your new data will be a trivial task.